# 'Object' does not contain a definition for 'datasource'

Tags: c#

```
    }
    private void btnfillcombo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmbPersons.datasource = b.Fillcombobox();
```

Datasource datatype doesn't show in the list. Any help ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: What is `cmbPersons`?

Comment: C# is case sensitive.

Comment: @ta.speot I Know its case sensitivity, but datasource supposed to be in the list of the datatypes but its missing for some reason...

Comment: Is it wpf or winforms? I didn't find any reference to datasource in tge msdn doc for wpf. Don't you mean to use ItemsSource?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be typo,

Try following

```
 cmbPersons.DataSource = b.Fillcombobox();
```

Comment: Nope doesnt work, already tried that. It supposed to be in the datatypes list. But i am only getting databindings,datasourceupdate but not JUST datasource.

Comment: is it a compile time error?

Comment: Yess, the following error; 'object' does not contain a definition for 'DataSource' and no extension method 'DataSource' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What is the declaring type of cmbPersons,

Comment: I am still a noob in c# but i assume, private object cmbPersons;

Comment: using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Domain;
using Session;

Comment: that is the problem. object does not have datasource. You need to type cast it to the type that has datasource. `((TypeNameThatHasDataSource)(cmbPersons)).DataSource = ...`